# is there a simple way to read an specific folder includes an specific phrase?

Tags: python, file, readfile

I want to read files from a specific folder which includes "*t1*" in the name of that folder. I used this code in python, but it didn't work.
code: path = "D:\first\***t1**\"
in the path, there are some characters instead of * before and after the phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `glob` module:

```
import glob    
files = glob.glob(r'D:\first\*t1*\*)
```

`*t1*` matches any directory in `D:\first` containing "t1" in the name, the last * matches everything in those directories.

**Note:** The `r''` string is necessary if you don't want to escape the backslashes in your path.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import os
 arr = os.listdir()
 files = [f for f in arr if "t1" in f]
```

first it gets all files from da directory, then filters out all files which don't have "t1" in their name.

Comment: I understood this code works for files, not folders.